# No new css loading

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that no new CSS will work. Here is the codePen: https://codepen.io/meamonb/pen/PmqKvB The new class I am trying to add is .email-sign-in-field. It won't work for any new classes or ids. I tried modifying the HTML or checking to see if the class name had a typo, but nothing works. I am using firebase serve to test it out, so that may be apart of the problem. There is no JS code so far. I am also using HTML5 boilerplate. Here is the CSS:

```
@import URL('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?
family=Montserrat:300,500');

#header {
color: white !important;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500 !important;
}

body {
background-color: #33658A;
}

#body {
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300 !important;
}


/* this is a tweak of bootstrap's .panel because creating my own 
results in a cluster */

.panel-notikal {
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 0 !important;
border-radius: 12px !important;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 20px 72px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) !important;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 20px 72px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) !important;
box-shadow: 0px 20px 72px -13px rgba(0,0,0,0.75) !important;
border-color: #ddd;
}



/* SIGN IN PANEL */
#sign-in-column {
margin-top: 25px;
}

#sign-in-body {
text-align: center;
}

#google-sign-in-button {
color: white;
background-color: #d34836;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-moz-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-ms-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-o-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
}

#google-sign-in-button:hover {
color: #d34836;
background-color: white;
}

#google-sign-in-button-icon {
padding-right: 8px;
}

#twitter-sign-in-button {
color: white;
background-color: #0084b4;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-moz-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-ms-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
-o-transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
cursor: pointer;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#twitter-sign-in-button:hover {
color: #0084b4;
background-color: white;
}

#twitter-sign-in-button-icon {
padding-right: 8px;
}

.email-sign-in-field {
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: It works fine.... add a background color to `.email-sign-in-field` and it displays

Comment: Seems to be working fine? Increase the margin and you will see it move.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for this:

1. Are you sure it's not a problem of browser caching you CSS ?
   Try refreshing the page with `Cntr+Shift+R` which would hard reload the page
2. Also the problem can be that the order in which you're defining CSS properties are overlapping. A previously defined same property can be overriding due to higher preference. You can use the `!important` to force the preference. Though I don't think that this is likely as your codepen suggests it's a new property

Comment: The hard reset did it! Thank you so much! It also fixed the problem with my favicons not loading!

Comment: Actually, just tried adding in a new property, and it doesn't work anymore. Even after doing the hard reload, and doing !important.

Comment: @MichaelBrennan, if the answer solved your problem, do you mind marking it as the 'accepted' answer

Comment: The problem is, I thought it worked, but unfortunately it doesn't.